# Sticky navbar flickering at one point when scrolling in Opera/Chrome browsers (Rendering bug?)

Tags: html, css

When scrolling down on my website the navigation bar flickers at one point. I did some research and found out this could be a rendering bug, although all the fixes on stackoverflow didn't solve my problem.

Here's a gif: https://i.gyazo.com/f0e5aa32b80650a38d735de13d61db6d.gif

The navigation bar has a sticky property, when I set it to fixed it solves the issue but I'd lose all benefits of having it sticky so I cannot use that as a solution.

I noticed it only happens in Chrome and Opera (as far as I know) and in Microsoft Edge it doesn't happen.

```
.nav-wrapper {
/* position: fixed; */
position: sticky;
top: 0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
clear: both;
```

Does anyone know a solution/fix I could try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also to set the .nav-wrapper height min-height and max-height to the same value

Comment: Adding this code worked for me! Thanks!
`max-height: 69px;
min-height: 69px;`

Comment: Great. Dont forget to vote up :) it will be appreciated. :)

Comment: I did but due to my reputation it wont get displayed. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Position: sticky;](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) doesn't have a vast amount of support, yet. Try using [position: fixed;](https://caniuse.com/#search=fixed)
Apologies, you did say this in your answer. To circumvent this limitation you may need to add some javascript to give you support for this functionality.

Here's an example of what you could do:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: As I said in my post the fixed position solves the issue but I'd lose all benefits of having it sticky so it's not a good solution for me. Thanks for the input though.